# Is it safe to cat or tail a file that's being written to using ofstream?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, macos, filesystems

I'm running a C++ script that writes to a file using `std::ofstream`. The script takes a very long time, and I want to monitor what's been written to the file as it's running.

Is it safe to `cat` my .txt file from a separate shell window? What about using `tail -f myfile.txt`?

I'm using macOS Catalina and I'm also running the script in a Ubuntu cloud instance.

Comment: You can both `cat` and `tail -f` the file.  I'm not sure what 'safe" means to you.

Comment: Yes, it is safe on those platforms.  Other platforms won't let you do that because the file would be exclusively locked.

Comment: It's fine, I do it all the time.  *nix systems (of which macOS is one, albeit with a lot of knobs on top) are very forgiving like that, although Windows is not.  `tail -f` is indeed what you're looking for, I would think.

Answer (score 1):

`cat` will print the current contents of the file and exit.

`tail -f` will keep waiting for new data to be appended to the file to print it until you terminate it manually.

Aside from the difference in behavior there is nothing "unsafe" about either method, at least not in a general sense.

I am not sure how they will behave if you move the stream position to write somewhere else than the end of the file.